# Rails active record query with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm

I have tables called `users`, `orders`, and `delivery_times` that are linked using the following relationship.

For table `User`:

```
belongs_to :orders
```

For table `orders`:

```
belongs_to :delivery_times
```

I want to write a query on table users using a condition on table delivery_times as shown:

```
User.includes(order: :delivery_time).where("delivery_times.start < ?",Time.now)
```

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "delivery_times"

However I get an error. Can I use the RoR ORM to make this query work using includes, even though I know there is a solution using joins?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a join for this kind of query, since you need the joint knowledge of the `delivery_times` table and the `users` table.

What `includes` actually does is it decides between `preload` and `eager_load` automatically and tries to always take the better one. In you case it will do an `eager_load`; have a look into this [article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

For the error you get, I guess it yould result from starting with `Users` and not `User`:

```
User.includes(order: :delivery_time).where("delivery_times.start < ?",Time.now)
```

Everything else seems correct to me.

Comment: i made edits and am using User. i still get the same error

Comment: You are also using the plural version in your belongs_to (`:orders`,`:delivery_times`) Those need to be singular. Can you post the relevant contents of all three models ?

Answer (score 0):

The better definition of relations between your models would be this:

[image: Relationships between models]

So your classes would look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end


class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :delivery_time
end

class DeliveryTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

The query you are making doesn't make any sense? What is the result that you are expecting?

If you want to get order that their delivery time is a specific time you can use scopes:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :delivery_time

  scope :ready_to_deliver, includes(:delivery_time).where("delivery_time.start < ? ", Time.now)
end
```

Then you can get orders that are ready to deliver like this:

```
ready_orders = Order.ready_to_deliver
```